# Laravel - PHP crashes (exit status 139) when action called

Tags: php, laravel

Whenever I call an action (just a regular PHP class) in my controller that in itself also calls another action, my PHP crashes with exit status 139 and I can't explain why. I have the issues in all cases where I call an action from another action.

This is what an example action looks like - pretty basic. Whenever the condition is met though, and the line `($this->removeUserFromCrewRoleAction)($crewRole);` is called, php just crashes, no error in the logs whatsoever.

```
class UpdateUserColumnAction
{
    private RemoveUserFromCrewRoleAction $removeUserFromCrewRoleAction;

    public function __construct(
        RemoveUserFromCrewRoleAction $removeUserFromCrewRoleAction
    ) {
        $this->removeUserFromCrewRoleAction = $removeUserFromCrewRoleAction;
    }

    public function __invoke(UserColumnData $data): CrewRole
    {
        $crewRole = EventContext::getEvent()->crewRoles()->findOrFail($data->role_id);

        // If user is changed / removed, trigger action
        if ($crewRole->user_id && $data->user_id !== $crewRole->user_id) {
            ($this->removeUserFromCrewRoleAction)($crewRole);
        }

        $crewRole->update([
            'user_id' => $data->user_id,
        ]);

        return $crewRole;
    }
}
```

This is how I call it in my controller:

```
public function updateUserColumn(
    UserColumnData $data,
    UpdateUserColumnAction $updateColumnAction
) {
    $this->authorize('update', CrewRole::findOrFail($data->role_id));

    try {
        $updateColumnAction($data);

        return redirect()->back()->with(['status' => 'crew-role-name-column-updated']);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        \Log::error($e->getMessage());
        return redirect()->back()->with(['error' => 'crew-role-column-updated-failed']);
    }
}
```

Am I doing something weird in PHP that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Do you have messages in the log file(s)? Laravel and WebServer (Apache?) have separate logs you can check for errors.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I'm running on Laravel sail currently. the only thing I see is: `INFO exited: php (exit status 139; not expected)`

Comment: It seems `$this->removeUserFromCrewRoleAction`  is not callable. Is `$this->removeUserFromCrewRoleAction` valid just before the call happens? If you want to output a log entry yourself check using [is_callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php)

Comment: @PeterKrebs Yes, is_callable returns true

Comment: The issue may be related to memory or literally issues with a disk (SSD or HDD), or you having compiled PHP yourself and there is something wrong with it. The only way is to try to debug. Try removing stuff, and see if, for example, remove some code from `RemoveUserFromCrewRoleAction` and try to find the line crashing inside it. Also, please, do share `RemoveUserFromCrewRoleAction`'s code, so we can also have a look at it.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Makes sense... I was so focused on the parent action that i didn't go into the parent action at all ‍♀️. I debugged it and in the end I found out that my `user` relation on the `CrewRole` model was self referencing like this:

public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->user();
    }

instead of using `belongsTo` as it should've. Didn't catch it cause i was so confused by PHP crashing. Now everything works. Thank you and thank you Peter, too.

Comment: No worries at all. I honestly never saw a `139` error when having a "recursive" or self-referencing function/method. It should throw an exception, but this is happening in this case. Any time you have issues likes this, remember to always go as deep as possible, and removing lines, until it stops giving errors, then you know which line is having issues, and you continue going deep and repeat until you find the culprit